# geolocation.watchposition does not show map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I put in the geolocation.watchPosition API, but when I run it on a browser, the map doesn't show up at all. How can I fix this issue?

```
<script>

if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    function showPositionOnMap(position)
    {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
        position.coords.longitude),
    
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: point,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
    
        mapDiv = document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions),
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            title: "You are here"
            });
    }

    var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPositionOnMap, errorMessage,
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 });
}

else
{
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With an existing `errorMessage` function, this code works well. Perhaps, your browser is blocking geolocation because you haven't allowed it.